# Appending 0's to make 1MB file with dd

Tags: unix, append, dd

I have a binary file `abc.bin` that is 512 bytes long, and I need to generate 1M (1024 x 1024 = 1048576) byte file by appending 0's (0x00) to the `abc.bin`. How can I do that with `dd` utility?

For example, `abc.bin` has 512 bytes of 0x01 ("11 ... 11"), and I need to have a helloos.bin that is 1048576 bytes ("11 ... 11000 ... 000"); the 0 is not '0', but 0x00, and the number of 0x00 is 1048576 - 512.

Comment: Your question is ambiguous about what you're trying to do -- by a "1M byte file", do you mean a file whose reported size is 1M and that you can read 1M of data from, or a file that actually has 1M allocated with 1M of 0's actually on the disk?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can tell `dd` to seek to the 1M position in the file, which has the effect of making its size at least 1M:

```
dd if=/dev/null of=abc.bin obs=1M seek=1
```

If you want to ensure that `dd` only extends, never truncates the file, add `conv=notrunc`:

```
dd if=/dev/null of=abc.bin obs=1M seek=1 conv=notrunc
```

If you're on a system with GNU coreutils (like, just about any Linux system), you can use the `truncate` command instead of `dd`:

```
truncate --size=1M abc.bin
```

If you want to be sure the file is only extended, never truncated:

```
truncate --size=\>1M abc.bin
```

Comment: These commands can create a sparse file, which might be really good or really bad depending on the OP's use case.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you actually mean to allocate 1M of zeroes on the disk, not just have a file whose reported length is 1MiB and reads as zeroes.

```
dd if=/dev/zero count=2047 bs=512 >> abc.bin
```

Answer (score 0):

This method also works:

1. Create a 1M file with 0(0x00)s - `dd if=/dev/zero of=helloos.bin bs=512 count=2048`
2. Write the `abc` on the created file - `dd of=helloos.bin conv=notrunc if=abc.bin`

Without the `conv=notrunc` option, I have only 512 byte file. I also can use `seek=N` to control the start position by skipping `N` blocks.